# Kyle Reese period in a death camp in Terminator

Tags: the-terminator-series

As quoted here:

> Kyle Reese : "Hunter-Killers. Patrol machines built in automated factories. Most of us were rounded up, put in camps for orderly disposal"

[pulls up his right sleeve, exposing a mark]

> Kyle Reese : "This is burned in by laser scan. Some of us were kept alive... to work... loading bodies. The disposal units ran night and day. We were that close to going out forever. But there was one man who taught us to fight, to storm the wire of the camps, to smash those metal motherf***ers into junk. He turned it around. He brought us back from the brink. His name is Connor. John Connor. Your son, Sarah... your unborn son"

Is there a canon mention in any of the Terminator franchise, including books, of how/when Kyle was captured and how long he was a captive?

Comment: According to Terminator: Future War, Kyle and his brother were scooped up by a band of roving (human) Skynet sympathisers and delivered to the Century Work Camp where he worked loading bodies into incinerators until he was rescued by John Connor three years later; https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Kyle_Reese

Comment: So was John Connor incarcerated a camp before he taught mankind to storm the wire, or did he storm it from the outside with  his resistance brethren?

Comment: In TSCC, it's mentioned that they were both in the camp; https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_106:_Dungeons_%26_Dragons. That's not canon though, hence why he was able to be in the camp in one property and rescue Kyle in another.

Comment: I've only noticed I've asked about John Connor in my main question, instead of Kyle.... I'll amend it shortly